# How do i show links at the top of Gitbook?

Tags: github, markdown, documentation, gitbook

At the top of https://docs.gitbook.com/ there are four links declared in the navigation for `Pricing`, `About`, `Terms`, `Privacy`. Where and how do you declare these links?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not standard links, but the closest in term of custommization would be:

"[Colllection customization / Header links](https://docs.gitbook.com/tour/customization/collection-customization#header-links)"

> You can add links to the header section of your documentation.
>
> For each link, you will need to set a URL and a text label.
>
> You could use header links to link to important parts of your documentation, or perhaps to link back to your main website.

> If your [`theme header` option](https://docs.gitbook.com/tour/customization/collection-customization#theme-header-options) is set to `none`, any header links you have configured will not be displayed.
> Make sure to choose one of the other theme header options so that your configured links are visible!

you have the [same header option for spaces](https://docs.gitbook.com/tour/customization/space-customization#header-links)